# CSRF: Do I need to use CSRF token for no cookies site?

Tags: php, forms, security, csrf, csrf-token

What I really would like to know is whether I need to add CSRF tokens to forms on sites which don't use cookies? I don't use cookies on my sites, I use sessions. Of course, for all my forms I use post method. If I need to use them, could you explain me why, because I read that CSRF attacks occur through cookies stored in a web browser. So, my logic is no cookies, no CSRF attacks. Am I correct?

A huge thank in advance.

Comment: Session information is generally stored in cookies. How are your sessions stored on the client side?

Comment: *”my logic is no cookies, no CSRF attacks”* — That is correct, but it’s not clear whether that really doesn’t apply in your case, unless you can clarify how your sessions work.

Comment: I have sessions, but don't use cookies, because they are in a browser and sessions are on a server side. For example, those sessions I set after user loggin:
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $result["usr_id"];
$_SESSION['user_loggedin'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $result['email'];

Comment: Those sessions use cookies!! The browser gets a cookie with a session id corresponding to its server side session! How else do you think the specific browser can be identified‽

Comment: I understand that a session id is stored in a PHPSESSID cookie. But there are no other site cookies. So, does in that case is needed to use CSRF token in a form or a form is safe from CSRF attacks even without CSRF token?

Comment: You *are* susceptible to CSRF attacks if you don’t use a token.

Comment: @deceze thank you. I didin't know that. I thought that it is needed to have other cookies than just a PHPSESSID cookie. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if I use sessions, but I don't store session ID in cookies, but in JS memory or in localstorage? And I am passing it as request body parameter in each request (or in headers). Then ID itself is a CSRF token. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Somnium I share the same opinion. Plus: Cookies are not reliable nowadays. Many browsers have many options about it and silly client can disable it at all or some extreme privacy protection can filter/block it. I pass session token to server as you mentioned with post data or headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, my logic is no cookies, no CSRF attacks. Am I correct?

No, you are not correct.

If your web client changes the state of the server (that includes changing data in the database used by the server) then a CSRF attack is possible and you need CSRF protection. If your web client doesn't change/mutate the state of the server (e.g. only reads, lists data) then CSRF is not needed.

The above applies regardless of any sessions and cookies.

For example, your webserver merely lists average daily temperatures for your favorite city for the last 10 years. Everyone can see this data so the server doesn't authenticate users and there are no sessions. And no cookies. However you don't want some "script kiddie" to write a script and call your API endpoint endlessly making millions of calls per day. Therefore you implement rate limiting. You also block for some time, say 1 hour or 1 day, the client IP address that is the source of API requests that exceed the limit. (Such blocking is mentioned as an example and whether it is a good idea or not is beyond the scope of our subject)

In this case you still need CSRF protection because an attacker can mount a CSRF attack resulting in the victim being blocked from using your server.